# Preparing search using like % and for each in php

Tags: php

My code is posting the entire table. Instead, it should only post the selected like term.....  $param="%{$_POST['search']}%";.

Sources: I mostly used these two articles to get my code: [Display a table in a foreach loop with database values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304535/display-a-table-in-a-foreach-loop-with-database-values) & [php mysqli prepared statement LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527659/php-mysqli-prepared-statement-like)

```
<table border="2" class="table-responsive" id="employee_table">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Update</th>
</tr>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
echo "Search Successful!";

 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?"); 
$param='%'.$_POST['search'].'%';
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $param, $param);
$stmt->execute();


$result = $stmt->get_result();
$i = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  foreach ($row as $r) {
      $i++;
    echo '<td> '.$r.'</td>';
 if($i % 6==0){
      echo '</tr><tr>';
   }}}
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to change your query to search in `first_name` or `last_name` (your original query would return all rows where `first_name` evaluates to true - essentialy any non empty string). Then you have to bind the parameter twice:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?"); 
$param='%'.$_POST['search'].'%';
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $param, $param);
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks. I made the changes. But for some reason, it still posts the entire table.

Comment: It should not - unless you enter search criteria that matches all the rows in the table.

Comment: Ok. I made one minor adjustment (on my index page) and it worked. Thanks for your help! Marked as solution.